# Django Invalid block tag on line 5: 'endfor'

Tags: python, django

Running through a beginner Django tutorial and ran into this `TemplateSyntaxError` and I'm not quite sure what's causing it:

```
Invalid block tag on line 5: 'endfor', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'.
Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Here's the template in question:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is that the complete template? You might not be loading the custom templates https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: It seems that you have included other HTML pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is exactly the template that is producing the error? It looks correct. I saw other persons having this error by putting a space between `{` and `%` (`{ %`) or using the wrong symbol (`{$ for foo in bar %}`.

Also check for invalid characters from copy/pasting, maybe retype the code.

Comment: Retyping it fixed it.  Still not sure what the exact problem was. Thanks!